# RegEx for Digits at End of Line

Tags: python, regex

I've got the following text in a text file and want to extract (1622,2096), (1755,1976) and the digits after the colon (ie 3.051753206) all from the second line.

```
Distances (mm):
  Distance from (1622,2096) to (1755,1976) with intensity 255: 3.051753206
Eye diameter (mm): 24
```

Here's the code I have currently, which I think should extract the digits at the end of the line:

```
match = re.search(r'Distance from \((\d+)),(\d+)\) to \((\d+)),(\d+)\) with intensity 255: (\d+)', line)
if match:
    d_mm = int(match.group(1))
    print(d_mm)
```

Can someone help me adjust my regex expression?

Comment: Try it like this in 3 capturing groups with the parentesis inside the group `Distance from (\(\d+,\d+\)) to (\(\d+,\d+\)) with intensity 255: (\d+(?:\.\d+))`  https://regex101.com/r/jQ8pqt/1

Comment: `Distance from \((\d+),(\d+)\) to \((\d+),(\d+)\) with intensity 255: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`. You have an extra closing parenthesis after the first and third group. And you need to handle the fractional part in the final group.

Comment: Is it the second line globally or repeated in your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slight change to the regex:

```
m = re.search(r'Distance from \((\d+),(\d+)\) to \((\d+),(\d+)\) with intensity 255: ([\d\.]+)', line)
m.groups()
```

The output is:

```
('1622', '2096', '1755', '1976', '3.051753206')
```

Comment: `[\d\.]+` is not a good idea because it will match multiple dots. It's better to use `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?` (or `(\d+(?:\.\d+)` if the fractional part are not optional).

Comment: If he knows his input, it's okay. I just don't understand why you have to escape that point in a character set. Use `[\d.]+`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract `(1622,2096)` and `(1755,1976)` then the capturing group should be around that whole part, and matching the parentesis should be also inside the group.

Matching the digits after the could be done adding an extra part to match the decimals.

```
\bDistance from (\(\d+,\d+\)) to (\(\d+,\d+\)) with intensity 255: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kNzPYS/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/r6kSrf)

```
import re 
 
line = ("Distances (mm):\n"
    "  Distance from (1622,2096) to (1755,1976) with intensity 255: 3.051753206\n"
    "Eye diameter (mm): 24")
match = re.search(r'\bDistance from (\(\d+,\d+\)) to (\(\d+,\d+\)) with intensity 255: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', line)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
    print(match.group(2))
    print(match.group(3))
```

Output

```
(1622,2096)
(1755,1976)
3.051753206
```